# when log in jupyterhub ,report 500 : Internal Server Error

Tags: python, jupyterhub

I install jupyterhub from source ,the version is 0.9.4. I try to log in with root user,but the server response 500 message.

> 500 : Internal Server Error
> Spawner failed to start [status=1]. The logs for root may contain details.
> You can try restarting your server from the home page.

then I click HOME PAGE and start my server ,it failed and shows message:

> Spawn failed: Server at http://192.168.183.148:47297/user/root/ didn't respond in 30 seconds

my jupyterhub_config.py

```
c.JupyterHub.authenticator_class = 'dummyauthenticator.DummyAuthenticator'
c.JupyterHub.bind_url = 'http://192.168.183.148:8000'
c.JupyterHub.data_files_path = '/usr/local/share/jupyterhub'
c.Spawner.ip = '192.168.183.148'
c.Authenticator.admin_users = {'root'}
c.Authenticator.whitelist = {'root','vinwin'}
c.PAMAuthenticator.encoding = 'utf8'
```

```
[root@localhost jupyter]# jupyterhub -f jupyterhub_config.py
```

console log:

```
[I 2021-12-01 03:46:26.857 JupyterHub app:1673] Using Authenticator:dummyauthenticator.dummyauthenticator.DummyAuthenticator

[I 2021-12-01 03:46:26.857 JupyterHub app:1673] Using Spawner: jupyterhub.spawner.LocalProcessSpawner-0.9.4

[I 2021-12-01 03:46:26.858 JupyterHub app:1055] Writing cookie_secret to /etc/jupyter/jupyterhub_cookie_secret

[I 2021-12-01 03:46:26.883 alembic.runtime.migration migration:155] Context impl SQLiteImpl.

[I 2021-12-01 03:46:26.884 alembic.runtime.migration migration:162] Will assume non-transactional DDL.

[I 2021-12-01 03:46:26.890 alembic.runtime.migration migration:517] Running stamp_revision  -> 896818069c98

[I 2021-12-01 03:46:26.931 JupyterHub proxy:431] Generating new CONFIGPROXY_AUTH_TOKEN

[I 2021-12-01 03:46:26.987 JupyterHub app:1855] Hub API listening on http://127.0.0.1:8081/hub/

[W 2021-12-01 03:46:26.988 JupyterHub proxy:565] Running JupyterHub without SSL.  I hope there is SSL termination happening somewhere else...

[I 2021-12-01 03:46:26.988 JupyterHub proxy:567] Starting proxy @ http://192.168.183.148:8000
03:46:27.217 [ConfigProxy] info: Proxying http://192.168.183.148:8000 to (no default)
03:46:27.220 [ConfigProxy] info: Proxy API at http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/routes
(node:53082) ExperimentalWarning: queueMicrotask() is experimental.
03:46:27.854 [ConfigProxy] info: 200 GET /api/routes 

[I 2021-12-01 03:46:27.855 JupyterHub proxy:301] Checking routes

[I 2021-12-01 03:46:27.855 JupyterHub proxy:370] Adding default route for Hub: / => http://127.0.0.1:8081
03:46:27.861 [ConfigProxy] info: Adding route / -> http://127.0.0.1:8081
03:46:27.862 [ConfigProxy] info: Route added / -> http://127.0.0.1:8081
03:46:27.863 [ConfigProxy] info: 201 POST /api/routes/ 

[I 2021-12-01 03:46:27.867 JupyterHub app:1912] JupyterHub is now running at http://192.168.183.148:8000

[I 2021-12-01 03:46:40.510 JupyterHub log:158] 302 GET / -> /hub (@192.168.183.1) 0.86ms

[I 2021-12-01 03:46:40.545 JupyterHub log:158] 302 GET /hub -> /hub/ (@192.168.183.1) 1.03ms

[W 2021-12-01 03:46:40.571 JupyterHub base:242] Invalid or expired cookie token

[I 2021-12-01 03:46:40.574 JupyterHub log:158] 302 GET /hub/ -> /hub/login (@192.168.183.1) 3.96ms

[I 2021-12-01 03:46:40.630 JupyterHub log:158] 200 GET /hub/login (@192.168.183.1) 31.31ms

[I 2021-12-01 03:46:45.414 JupyterHub base:499] User logged in: root

[I 2021-12-01 03:46:45.415 JupyterHub log:158] 302 POST /hub/login?next= -> /user/root/ (root@192.168.183.1) 11.03ms

[I 2021-12-01 03:46:45.451 JupyterHub log:158] 302 GET /user/root/ -> /hub/user/root/ (@192.168.183.1) 0.77ms

[I 2021-12-01 03:46:45.530 JupyterHub spawner:1100] Spawning jupyterhub-singleuser '--ip="192.168.183.148"' --port=46793
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/jupyterhub-singleuser", line 3, in <module>
    from jupyterhub.singleuser import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyterhub/singleuser.py", line 34, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 81, in <module>
    from .services.kernels.kernelmanager import MappingKernelManager
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/kernelmanager.py", line 19, in <module>
    from jupyter_client.session import Session
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyter_client/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .asynchronous import AsyncKernelClient  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyter_client/asynchronous/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .client import AsyncKernelClient  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyter_client/asynchronous/client.py", line 6, in <module>
    from jupyter_client.channels import HBChannel
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyter_client/channels.py", line 47
    time_to_dead: float = 1.0
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

[W 2021-12-01 03:46:55.506 JupyterHub web:1787] 500 GET /hub/user/root/ (192.168.183.1): Spawner failed to start [status=1]. The logs for root may contain details.

[E 2021-12-01 03:46:55.520 JupyterHub log:150] {
      "X-Forwarded-Proto": "http",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
      "X-Forwarded-For": "192.168.183.1",
      "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
      "Cookie": "jupyterhub-hub-login=\"2|1:0|10:1638348405|20:jupyterhub-hub-login|44:NTAxYTI1MTFlMjEyNDk0OGEyMzcxMGE4YmQyZTY0MTc=|7226825397d8c04df83eb08b3d6643e6a050f12ac549f65bae0dacffde3b36f6\"; jupyterhub-session-id=7f07873d8ead4f2dbc0684c4e951d7fc",
      "Accept-Language": "zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,zh-TW;q=0.7,zh-HK;q=0.5,en-US;q=0.3,en;q=0.2",
      "Host": "192.168.183.148:8000",
      "Referer": "http://192.168.183.148:8000/hub/login",
      "X-Forwarded-Host": "192.168.183.148:8000",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36",
      "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
      "X-Forwarded-Port": "8000",
      "Connection": "close"
    }

[E 2021-12-01 03:46:55.520 JupyterHub log:158] 500 GET /hub/user/root/ (root@192.168.183.1) 10042.81ms

[W 2021-12-01 03:47:14.769 JupyterHub user:510] root's server never showed up at http://192.168.183.148:46793/user/root/ after 30 seconds. Giving up

[E 2021-12-01 03:47:14.805 JupyterHub gen:624] Exception in Future <Task finished coro=<BaseHandler.spawn_single_user.<locals>.finish_user_spawn() done, defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyterhub/handlers/base.py:619> exception=TimeoutError("Server at http://192.168.183.148:46793/user/root/ didn't respond in 30 seconds",)> after timeout
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 618, in error_callback
        future.result()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 294, in result
        raise self._exception
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 240, in _step
        result = coro.send(None)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyterhub/handlers/base.py", line 626, in finish_user_spawn
        await spawn_future
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyterhub/user.py", line 528, in spawn
        raise e
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyterhub/user.py", line 502, in spawn
        resp = await server.wait_up(http=True, timeout=spawner.http_timeout)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyterhub/utils.py", line 197, in wait_for_http_server
        timeout=timeout
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyterhub/utils.py", line 155, in exponential_backoff
        raise TimeoutError(fail_message)
    TimeoutError: Server at http://192.168.183.148:46793/user/root/ didn't respond in 30 seconds
```

I have the same error in ubuntu and centos.
Both of them installed python3 and python2.

Comment: i tried two ways to install jupyterhub:
`python3 -m pip install jupyterhub-0.9.4.tar.gz`
 and
`python3 setup.py build && python3 setup.py install && python3 -m pip install . `

Comment: do you have IP `192.168.183.148`? Maybe use `127.0.0.01` or `0.0.0.0`

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. thanks for posting the full stacktrace - super helpful!

Comment: i deploy it in vmware not localhost.

Answer (score 0):

See this github issue: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/6100

Recent releases of jupyter_client are not compatible with python ≤ 3.5. You need to either use a more recent version of python or pin jupyter_client to 6.1.12 or earlier.

Comment: The error is being raised by `"/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyter_client/channels.py"` so you are using python 3.5 - maybe inside a docker container?

Comment: thanks ,but it is useless,i have tried python3.9.7 and notebook 5.0.0,python 3.5.0 and notebook 5.6.0.

Comment: i deploy it in vmware,centos and ubuntu both tried.